# Convert object string to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, object

How can I convert a string that describes an object into a JSON string using JavaScript (or jQuery)?

e.g: Convert this (*NOT* a valid JSON string):

```
var str = "{ hello: 'world', places: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Australia'] }"
```

into this:

```js
str = '{ "hello": "world", "places": ["Africa", "America", "Asia", "Australia"] }'
```

I would love to avoid using `eval()` if possible.

Comment: Why is your string not valid JSON in the first place?  How are you generating that?

Comment: The string is stored in a `data`-attrubute, like this: `<div data-object="{hello:'world'}"></div>` and I don't want to use single quotes in the HTML(so it is probably not to be trusted)

Comment: @snorpey: `<div data-object='{"hello":"world"}'></div>` is 100% valid HTML (what does single quotes have to do with trusting it or not?). If you do it this way, you can just `JSON.parse` it and it'll work fine.  **Note:** the keys need to be quoted too.

Comment: @Rocket thanks for your efforts! I just wanted to find a way around having to use single quotes in HTML (even though it is 100% valid) and JSON notation.

Comment: @snorpey: They way around is not to put JSON in a HTML attribute in the first place.  I guess you *could* use double quotes, and escape the ones in the JSON `<div data-object="{\"hello\":\"world\"}"></div>`.  If you don't want to use valid JSON in the attribute, then you're gonna have to make your own format and parse it yourself.

Comment: These are just tips instead of answer. - You can use [http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/) to verify my JSON. - While passing JSON string from code behind mindful of adding appropriate escape characters.

Answer (score 184, accepted):

**If the string is from a trusted source**, you could use `eval` then `JSON.stringify` the result. Like this:

```
var str = "{ hello: 'world', places: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Australia'] }";
var json = JSON.stringify(eval("(" + str + ")"));
```

Note that when you `eval` an object literal, it has to be wrapped in parentheses, otherwise the braces are parsed as a block instead of an object.

I also agree with the comments under the question that it would be much better to just encode the object in valid JSON to begin with and avoid having to parse, encode, then presumably parse it *again*. HTML supports single-quoted attributes (just be sure to HTML-encode any single quotes inside strings).

Comment: this does not make sense, if string is from trusted source, why we convert it instead we make it as valid json.

Comment: @allenhwkim The idea is to convert from invalid JSON to valid JSON, so `eval` converts the string to a JavaScript object (which works, as long as the string represents valid JavaScript, even if it's not valid JSON). Then `JSON.stringify` converts from an object back to a (valid) JSON string. Calling `eval` is dangerous if the string is not from a trusted source because it could literally run any JavaScript which opens up the possibility of cross-site scripting attacks.

Comment: eval will still do bad things in this case if the string is constructed, for example, like this: var str = "(function() {console.log(\"bad\")})()";

Comment: Using eval() will execute JS code. It can be easily abused.

Comment: @allenhwkim: we never trust any source. Trust in IT means check, check and check again.

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Answer (score 112):

Your string is not valid JSON, so `JSON.parse` (or jQuery's `$.parseJSON`) won't work.

One way would be to use `eval` to "parse" the "invalid" JSON, and then `stringify` it to "convert" it to valid JSON.

```
var str = "{ hello: 'world', places: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Australia'] }"
str = JSON.stringify(eval('('+str+')'));
```

I suggest instead of trying to "fix" your invalid JSON, you start with valid JSON in the first place.  How is `str` being generated, it should be fixed there, before it's generated, not after.

**EDIT**: You said (in the comments) this string is stored in a data attribute:

```
<div data-object="{hello:'world'}"></div>
```

I suggest you fix it here, so it can just be `JSON.parse`d.  First, both they keys and values need to be quoted in double quotes.  It should look like (single quoted attributes in HTML are valid):

```
<div data-object='{"hello":"world"}'></div>
```

Now, you can just use `JSON.parse` (or jQuery's `$.parseJSON`).

```
var str = '{"hello":"world"}';
var obj = JSON.parse(str);
```

Answer (score 50):

[**jQuery.parseJSON**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

```
str = jQuery.parseJSON(str)
```

Edit. This is provided you have a valid JSON string

Comment: true I saw the question as how to convert JSON string to object

Answer (score 43):

Use simple code in the link below :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ie/cc836466%28v=vs.94%29.aspx

```
var jsontext = '{"firstname":"Jesper","surname":"Aaberg","phone":["555-0100","555-0120"]}';
var contact = JSON.parse(jsontext);
```

and reverse

```
var str = JSON.stringify(arr);
```

Comment: Converting jsontext to a String object via new String(jsontext) is probably even better, for type safety.

Comment: @fuzzyanalysis: No, primitive wrappers should never be used.

Comment: JSON.parse() should be the accepted answer here as stated by @LouiseMcMahon

Answer (score 29):

I hope this little function converts invalid JSON string to valid one.

```
function JSONize(str) {
  return str
    // wrap keys without quote with valid double quote
    .replace(/([\$\w]+)\s*:/g, function(_, $1){return '"'+$1+'":'})    
    // replacing single quote wrapped ones to double quote 
    .replace(/'([^']+)'/g, function(_, $1){return '"'+$1+'"'})         
}
```

Result

```
let invalidJSON = "{ hello: 'world',foo:1,  bar  : '2', foo1: 1, _bar : 2, $2: 3, 'xxx': 5, \"fuz\": 4, places: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Australia'] }"
JSON.parse(invalidJSON) 
//Result: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token h VM1058:2
JSON.parse(JSONize(invalidJSON)) 
//Result: Object {hello: "world", foo: 1, bar: "2", foo1: 1, _bar: 2…}
```

Comment: We're trying to de-evalify b using JSON.parse our code and this looks like a good solution. We're still going to have to handle constant replacement  by hand, but at least this allows to contain those cases.

Comment: It's almost perfect. Does not work when `:`  is in one of values.

Comment: eval is pure evil, I think this is the way to go

Comment: absolute geinus

Answer (score 9):

Use with caution (because of `eval()`):

```
function strToJson(str) {
  eval("var x = " + str + ";");
  return JSON.stringify(x);
}
```

call as:

```
var str = "{ hello: 'world', places: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Australia'] }";
alert( strToJson(str) );
```

Comment: To the anonymous down-voter. I challenge you to provide a better solution. Apart from that a reason for the down-vote would be nice.

Comment: Why was this down-voted?  Yes, `eval` is bad, but his string is not valid JSON, so he can't use `JSON.parse`.

Comment: @Rocket: You are wrong. a) `eval()` is the only way to do it. b) I cautioned the OP about it. c) Look at Matthew Crumley's answer and think of a better explanation. (Oh, and d) the statement `eval()` is bad is nonsense in this generalized form.)

Comment: I'm wrong for agreeing with you?  That comment was asking why this was-voted.  I was explaining why `eval` has to be used here.  Did you see *my* answer?

Comment: @Rocket: Ah, misunderstanding right there. Sorry, I thought the down-vote was yours. :)

Comment: @Tomalak I've down-voted you. You're right that `eval()` is the only way, but your solution doesn't work – you forget add round brackets. See my post, or post from @Matthew Crumley

Comment: @kuboslav: It works fine, did you even test it?  He's doing `eval("var x = " + str + ";")` which is totally valid JS.  You don't need to do `var x = ({a:12})`.

Comment: @Rocket Yes, I've tested it – it doesn't work. See my post before answer.

Comment: @kuboslav: Then you're testing it wrong, because it works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/ExHWk/

Comment: @Rocket – Again: _Note that when you `eval` an object literal, it has to be wrapped in parentheses, otherwise the braces are parsed as a block instead of an object_

Comment: @kuboslav: Again: He's not `eval`ing an *object literal*.  He's `eval`ing a line of code that sets a variable to an object.  I'll ask you again, **Did you test it?**  It works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/ExHWk/

Comment: @kuboslav I usually test things before I post them here. Still there might be errors in them or they might not work everywhere. I'd appreciate a comment if that's the case. An uncommented downvote is not helpful at all - not for me and not for anybody else who might wonder. (Apart from that, I'm not into down-voting. I leave just a comment even under dead-wrong answers. But maybe that's just me.)

Comment: @Tomalak I'm sorry, but I write slowly on notebook keyboard. In future I'll first write comment and then would down-vote. I've down-voted because it doesn't work in my IE7.

Comment: @kuboslav It does not work in IE7 because IE7 does not have native JSON support. It will start to work as soon as you use [`json2.js`](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js). Don't be so trigger-happy.

Comment: @kuboslav: Why are you still using IE7, it's 2012, get with the times :-P  (P.S. It doesn't work in IE7 because it doesn't have native `JSON`, nothing to do with the `eval`.  You can use Crockford's [JSON shim](https://raw.github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/master/json2.js) to add JSON support to IE7.)

Comment: @Tomalak you can utilize the onclick attribute of a dummy element to accomplish the same thing, so eval() isn't the _only_ way (technically speaking). I left an answer to show how this alternative method works in practice.

Comment: @csu Isn't that method using `eval()` as well, under the hood? I would not be surprised.

Comment: @Tomalak if we want to be uber technical, eval() is a call for the JS engine to parse and run script content, and every textual bit of code (onclick, etc) or script tag invokes the same basic mechanism that backs eval(). The one benefit textual script tags, attributes, and new Function creation can provide, is they are generally easier to optimize (once cast, and cached) for reuse. Constantly using eval to reevaluate the same textual code strings is much harder to optimize in the same way. As the OP asked for no explicit use of eval(), I felt the solution I provided fit the bill.

Answer (score 4):

Disclaimer: don't try this at home, or for anything that requires other devs taking you seriously:

```
JSON.stringify(eval('(' + str + ')'));
```

There, I did it.
Try not to do it tho, eval is BAD for you. As told above, use Crockford's JSON shim for older browsers (IE7 and under)

This method requires your string to be valid *javascript*, which will be converted to a javascript object that can then be serialized to JSON.

*edit:* fixed as Rocket suggested.

Comment: It should be `JSON.stringify(eval('('+str+')'));`, not that I condone `eval`, but his string isn't valid JSON so `JSON.parse` doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

I put my answer for someone who are interested in this old thread.

I created the [HTML5 data-* parser](https://github.com/tokkonopapa/jQuery-parseData) for jQuery plugin and [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tokkonoPapa/S6St8/) which convert a malformed JSON string into a JavaScript object without using `eval()`.

It can pass the HTML5 data-* attributes bellow:

```
<div data-object='{"hello":"world"}'></div>
<div data-object="{hello:'world'}"></div>
<div data-object="hello:world"></div>
```

into the object:

```
{
    hello: "world"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use "eval" then JSON.stringify then JSON.parse to the result.

```
 var errorString= "{ hello: 'world', places: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Australia'] }";
 var jsonValidString = JSON.stringify(eval("(" + errorString+ ")"));
 var JSONObj=JSON.parse(jsonValidString);
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your best and safest bet would be [JSON5 – JSON for Humans](https://github.com/json5/json5). It is created specifically for that use case.

```js
const result = JSON5.parse("{ hello: 'world', places: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Australia'] }");

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json5/0.5.1/json5.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Using new Function() is better than eval, but still should only be used with safe input.

```
const parseJSON = obj => Function('"use strict";return (' + obj + ')')();

console.log(parseJSON("{a:(4-1), b:function(){}, c:new Date()}"))
// outputs: Object { a: 3, b: b(), c: Date 2019-06-05T09:55:11.777Z }
```

Sources:
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Do_not_ever_use_eval!), [2ality](http://2ality.com/2014/01/eval.html)

Answer (score 2):

Douglas Crockford has a converter, but I'm not sure it will help with bad JSON to good JSON.

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Comment: This doesn't really help, as the string isn't valid JSON.

Answer (score 2):

There's a much simpler way to accomplish this feat, just hijack the onclick attribute of a dummy element to force a return of your string as a JavaScript object:

```
var jsonify = (function(div){
  return function(json){
    div.setAttribute('onclick', 'this.__json__ = ' + json);
    div.click();
    return div.__json__;
  }
})(document.createElement('div'));

// Let's say you had a string like '{ one: 1 }' (malformed, a key without quotes)
// jsonify('{ one: 1 }') will output a good ol' JS object ;)
```

**Here's a demo:** http://codepen.io/csuwldcat/pen/dfzsu (open your console)

Answer (score 1):

You have to write round brackets, because without them `eval` will consider code inside curly brackets as block of commands.

```
var i = eval("({ hello: 'world', places: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Australia'] })");
```

Answer (score 0):

For your simple example above, you can do this using 2 simple regex replaces:

```
var str = "{ hello: 'world', places: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Australia'] }";
str.replace(/(\w+):/g, '"$1":').replace(/'/g, '"');
 => '{ "hello": "world", "places": ["Africa", "America", "Asia", "Australia"] }'
```

**Big caveat**: This naive approach assumes that the object has no strings containing a `'` or `:` character. For example, I can't think of a good way to convert the following object-string to JSON without using `eval`:

```
"{ hello: 'world', places: [\"America: The Progressive's Nightmare\"] }"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the quirks of it, you can convert your string via `babel-standalone`

```js
var str = "{ hello: 'world', places: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Australia'] }";

function toJSON() {
  return {
    visitor: {
      Identifier(path) {
        path.node.name = '"' + path.node.name + '"'
      },
      StringLiteral(path) {
        delete path.node.extra
      }
    }
  }
}
Babel.registerPlugin('toJSON', toJSON);
var parsed = Babel.transform('(' + str + ')', {
  plugins: ['toJSON']
});
var json = parsed.code.slice(1, -2)
console.log(JSON.parse(json))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

var str = "{ hello: 'world', places: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Australia'] }"
var fStr = str
.replace(/([A-z]*)(:)/g, '"$1":')
.replace(/'/g, "\"")

console.log(JSON.parse(fStr))[image]

Sorry I am on my phone, here is a pic.

Answer (score 0):

A solution with one regex and not using eval:

```
str.replace(/([\s\S]*?)(')(.+?)(')([\s\S]*?)/g, "$1\"$3\"$5")
```

This I believe should work for multiple lines and all possible occurrences (/g flag) of single-quote 'string' replaced with double-quote "string".

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "{ hello: 'world', places: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Australia'] }";
var json = JSON.stringify(eval("(" + str + ")"));
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you have to try this:

```
str = jQuery.parseJSON(str)
```

Comment: Question specified "or jQuery" and this is the perfect solution if you have it available.