# Convert C# String into Javascript Object/JSON

Tags: c#, json, jquery, javascriptserializer

I have a Javascript object like this:

```
var jsonDataActual = { 
                       "source": [{
                                    "name": "testCaption0", 
                                    "desc": "testDescrip0", 
                                    "values": [{ 
                                                 "from": "/Date(1338811241074)/", 
                                                   "to": "/Date(1346760041074)/", 
                                                "label": "testLabel0", 
                                          "customClass": "GanttRed"
                                               }] 
                                 }], 
                       "navigate": "scroll", 
                        "scale": "weeks", 
                        "maxScale": "months", 
                        "minScale": "days", 
                    "itemsPerPage": 11, 
                     "onItemClick": function (data) { }, 
                      "onAddClick": function (dt, rowId) { } 

                 };
```

it works fine for me. Now, because of my requirement and need, am making this entire object(including braces i.e.{ } and semicolon ;) as a string on server side (C#) and returning it to an ajax call (web Method) using a server side method:

in the server side method I do something like this:

```
return  new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(jsonData);
```

but now this entire returned data (inside `Success: function(msg){ var s=msg.d}` ) is treated as string, hence it doesn't work.

I tried these:

```
  1. var obj = eval('{' + msg.d +'}'); (removing beginning and ending braces in msg.d)
         typeof(obj) is string. failed

  2. eval('var obj ='+msg.d);  (including beginning and ending braces in msg.d)
         typeof(obj) is string. failed

  3. var obj= jQuery.parseJson(msg.d);
        typeof(obj) is string. failed
  4. var obj = new Object();
     //var obj = {}; 
      obj=jQuery.parseJson(msg.d).
      typeof(obj) is string. failed.
```

please help. How can I convert a server side returned json into object?

Why not is it working for me??. Is it because of structure of my json object??

and why does `jsonDataActual` works for me but not when sent as a string???

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086404/string-to-object-in-js) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9036429/convert-object-string-to-json)..

Please Help.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found out solution to my specific problem.

I was constructing a string variable with my json data as its value. And then I would return this string to the client side function(the one making ajax request). i.e.

Server side method

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetJsonData()
{
    string jsonData = String.Empty;
    foreach(var dataItem in objEntireData.Items)
    {
         //  jsonData +=  
    }
   return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(result);
}
```

but it was not working. So instead of constructing a string  variable and serializing it, I wrote a class with specific structure and sent it in the return statement(after serialzing).

i.e. see below classes

```
    public class A
    {
        public A()
        {
            Values = new List<B>();
        }
        public string prop1 {get; set;}
        public List<B> Values { get; set; }
    }
    public class B
    {
        public string prop2 { get; set; }
        public string prop3 { get; set; }
    }
```

and I would use this class as below:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetJsonData()
{
          List<A> objA = new List<A>();
          A objAItem = new A();
          foreach (var dbItem in objDataBaseValues)
          {
                objA.prop1 = "test";
                B objBItem = new B();
                b.prop2="value";
                b.prop3="value";
                objA.Values.Add(objBItem);
          }
        return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(objA);

  }
```

wrapping up my entire data into a class structure and then serializing this worked for me. my client side function successfully recognized it as an object i.e.

```
 $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ProjectGanttChart.aspx/getData",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        var jsonData = jQuery.parseJSON(msg.d);
                        populateGantt(jsonData);
                     }
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var json=(typeof msg.d) == 'string' ? eval('(' + msg.d + ')') : msg.d;
```

Comment: .it didn't work for me. as usual, typeof(json) is string which implies, eval didn't convert my string to object

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this many times before. When a WCF service is decrypting the returned data into JSON, string data will always have " " around it. You should always return objects, or lists of objects from your WCF service - even if these are custom objects created at your service level.

So, your service should be, say:

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebGet(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "/Test?testId={testId}", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                   ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        List<TestObjectJSON> Test(int testId);
```

This will then do the deserialization for you on the service side, without using the Serializer.

Comment: @thexdixon..see am not using a WCF or a webservice. my method is simply kept on an aspx page. plane asp.net.

Comment: I'm not too sure how the parsing is done on a WebMethod, but if you're using .NET 4+, then I can imagine it being the same serialization as a service. Could you try doing the custom object approach quickly and seeing if that works?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I convert a server side returned json into object?

You can use `JSON.parse` to do that.

Example:

```
a = [1, 2];
x = JSON.stringify(a); // "[1,2]"
o = JSON.parse(x); // [1, 2];
```

Comment: god. even JSON.parse cudn't help. again I got string as a result of JSON.parse(msg.d) and not an object..goddd

Comment: what do you mean you want an object? you can put a string into a object using `var o = {"s":"string here"}; // now o.s = "string here"!`

Comment: wow...please read the question goldenparrot. Besides, var o={"s":"string here"}, is no use to me, I want "string here" to be an object and not it to be contained inside another object. i.e. "string here" has many keys and values inside it, i need to access them. i hope m making sense

Comment: Oh! My mistake. Btw, can you try: `var obj= jQuery.parseJson(jQuery.parseJson(msg.d));`