# Ajax sending multiple values

Tags: jquery, ajax

Normally Ajax syntax is

```
ajax('fn_name'['filter_value'],'target')
```

But I am using 3 filters in my page and so wanted to send all 3 values to ajax call.

```
ajax('fn_name'['filter1','filter2','filter3'],'target')
```

Is above syntax correct? Its not working....
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your actual code?

Comment: Share your code here.. we can't tell you person name by face.. :)

Answer (score 2):

To send these multiple values, i would serialize that array into JSON then process the JSON data in whatever backend is receiving it.

```
var filterArray = { 'fn_name': ['filter1', 'filter2', 'filter3'] };

ajax(JSON.stringify(filterArray));
```

[Convert object string to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9036429/convert-object-string-to-json)