# JavaScript making an array of key value object from a string

Tags: javascript

I have a string like this

```
var information = 'name:ozil,age:22,gender:male,location:123 street';
```

I want to make an array of key value object like this

```
var informationList=[
    {
       'key':'name',
       'value':'ozil'
    },
    {
       'key':'gender',
       'value':'male'
    },
    {
       'key':'location',
       'value':'123 street'
    },

]
```

Comment: And what have tried so far? SO is not a code-request community.

Comment: google javascript `split` function

Comment: Naive approach: `'name:ozil,age:22,gender:male,location:123 street'.split(',').map(function(el) { var p = el.split(':'); return {key: p[0], value: p[1]}; })`

Comment: HTH
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9036429/convert-object-string-to-json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var list = [];
var pairs = information.split(',');
for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
    var p = pairs[i].split(':');
    list.push({
        key: p[0],
        value: p[1]
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `split` and `map`:

```js
var information = 'name:ozil,age:22,gender:male,location:123 street',
    result = information.split(',').map(function(item){
      var arr = item.split(':');
      
      return {
        key: arr[0],
        value: arr[1]
      }
    });


document.write(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
var input = "name:ozil,age:22,gender:male,location:123 street";
var temp = input.split(",");
var result = [];
for(var i=0; i < temp.length; i++) {
    var temp2 = temp[i].split(":");
    result.push({key:temp2[0], value:temp2[1]});
}
console.log(result);
```

result now contains what you specified.