# AngularJS populate select dropdown from SQLite database

Tags: javascript, angularjs, database, sqlite

I have created a cross platform app using AngularJS, Monaca and Onsen UI.

I have created a SQLite Database to store information locally in the app to be available offline at any time.

I create the SQLite Database and Table and insert values into it and all this is working as it should - below for sample code of CREATE and INSERT form my views *app.js controller*.

**app.js**

```
function createDB(tx)
{
    tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tb_my_list');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tb_my_list (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name, score)');

    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO tb_my_list (id, name, score) VALUES (01, "Name 1", 111)');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO tb_my_list (id, name, score) VALUES (02, "Name 1", 222)');   
}
```

I then declare a variable to hold the results from the SQLite Database to access this in my *view*.

```
$scope.DatabaseData = [];

function queryDB(tx)
{
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM tb_my_list', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
}

function querySuccess(tx, results)
{
    var len = results.rows.length; // Shows "2" - as INSERTED values
    $scope.databaseData = results; // Returns [object SQLResultSet]
}
```

In my *view* I have a *select* dropdown box where I want to populate the dropdown items with the values fro my SQLite Database **name** column.

I try to use *ng-options* but no values are shown in the dropdown list. Below is my views select where I try to populate the values.

```
<select ng-model="myDataDropDown" ng-options="databaseData.id as databaseData.name for databaseData in DatabaseData"><option value="" label="-- Please Select --"></option></select>
```

Can I access the **name** values like this directly or do I need to convert from SQLite to JSON first?

Comment: You need to convert your data to json with http://stackoverflow.com/a/9036552/1618775

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a normal array object from the response like this

```
 function querySuccess(tx, results)
{
    var len = results.rows.length; 
    var output_results = [];

    for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
       var theItem = results.rows.item(i);
       output_results.push(theItem.name);
    }
    $scope.databaseData = output_results;
}
```

then use a simple ngoption like this

```
ng-options="item for item in databaseData
```

However IF you want a name value pair  in list then... its bit different.

```
 function querySuccess(tx, results)
{
    var len = results.rows.length; 
    var output_results = [];

    for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
       var theItem = results.rows.item(i);
       output_results.push({id: theItem.id,'name': theItem.name});
    }
    $scope.databaseData = output_results;
}
```

then use a complex ngoption like this

```
ng-options="option.name for option in databaseData track by option.id"
```