# nodejs accept data from api problem with json

Tags: node.js, api, express

I am trying to get some JSON data from the API provided by the vendor, but i am getting error i try google it, in many comments people say to use `JSON.Stringify` but in my case `JSON.Stringify` didnt help me it returns an empty array like {}

repose from the api are as follow

```
[{ SYMBOL: 'FOREX',
CODE: 'REG',
LST: '219.50',
LTP: '12:52:35'}]
```

but my desire response is

```
[{ "SYMBOL" : "FOREX",
"CODE": "REG",
"LTP": '219.50',
"LST": '12:52:35'}]
```

Comment: Can you please share error logs?

Comment: @RahulPatil error i recive when i open app.use(body.parser())

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token S in JSON at position 5
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at parse (D:\nodeGit\finpocket\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:89:19)`

Comment: when i use 
bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/*+json' })

it returns me empty { }

Comment: What your getting for `response[0].SYMBOL` ?

Comment: @ŞivāSankĂr Not define

Comment: From where you copied your response ? CMD/Browser/Postman ?

Answer (score 0):

Your response is on text, To convert text to JSON string,

```
let text = `[{ SYMBOL: 'FOREX',
CODE: 'REG',
LST: '219.50',
LTP: '12:52:35'}]`

let jsonStr = JSON.stringify(eval("(" + text + ")")); // Convert Object String to JSON
console.log(jsonStr);
```

**Note :** Make sure that your vendor is trusted source, Because `eval` opens up your code for **injection attacks**, If your are worry about this, Please contact your vendor to provide JSON response.

*Reference : [Convert object string to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9036429/convert-object-string-to-json)*

Comment: Eval is Evil. Do you really suggest evaluating the response from an API ? This is as bad as it can be.

Comment: Hope that the string from trusted source.

Comment: The source must be trusted, as well as the network. This is not acceptable for any web app. Evaluating from an external source is the worst possible scenario.

Comment: Answer updated to give warning the use of `eval()`. Now depends on the requirement/API source they will decide to go with `eval()` or not

Answer (score 0):

If the JSON result provided by the vendor's API is indeed this :

```
[{ SYMBOL: 'FOREX',
CODE: 'REG',
LST: '219.50',
LTP: '12:52:35'}]
```

I have to inform you that this is invalid JSON. In JSON, the properties should be strings between *double-quotes*, otherwise it cannot be parsed.

Your desired response is the correct form. There is likely an error in the way the vendor is forming the output.

tl;dr : Your vendor's API is giving you a JavaScript Object, not JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so what i did is use STRINGFY as a middleware and that solve my problem thanks for your help guys really appreciatable.